# Recommended book on "Dynamic Model Learning" related to "System Identification"?

Tags: dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, machine-learning, system-identification

I need to take a course on so-called "Dynamic Model Learning" related to "System Identification" + "Machine Learning stuff". But my backrgound is more on Computer Science and Electrical Engineering though.

The recommended book for this course is 
Lennart Ljung, System identification: Theory for the user, 2nd ed. Prentice-Hall 1999.

When I see the above book, the notations are just so different that I am not used with it. I am just wondering, what other "good" books that you can recommend for such a course (I understand that we all have different tastes though)? Also, if you know any video lectures on such a course (simple google search is not helping me :S)